# Read boolean session variable in WordPress after checking in functions

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I need to check if there is a session on every WordPress page. I used add_action Init with the following code:

```
function check_session() {
    $se;
    if ( session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE ) {
        $se = false;
    } elseif ( session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ) {
        session_start();
        if ( isset( $_SESSION['mysession'] ) ) {
            $se = true;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'check_session');
```

Now, I want to show prices or others depending on whether or not that session exists. I tried to set a boolean variable after checking the session and programming the code based on that variable, but I can not read it in the file of my template, neither in the index.php or head.php, I guess it will not be visible. What is the way to read the boolean variable in the files of the wordpress theme, or is there a better way to do this? I have read about global variables but everyone advises against using them.

To see if anyone can take my doubts away, I greet you!

Comment: $_SESSION['sessionIsSet'] = true

In your template you know can access $_SESSION['sessionIsSet']

Comment: $ _SESSION['dataSession'] will contain a small array of strings (user id, privileges ...). I already know that I can print the value of $ _SESSION['dataSession'] on each file in my template. What I intend is: with the add_action Init, check that the session exists and generate a variable that will use in the template, but not declare it in each template, if this is possible. Otherwise, what other way is there?